# Two variables with the same name in different objects altering each others' values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7

I have two `UITableView` objects that both have an array named `sectionHeaders` that is used as a reference object to provide, no surprise, the header names for a given section in the table. The first table view has it as an `NSMutableArray` and adds the headers dynamically as they are needed. The second view uses an `NSArray` and creates the array using the `@[item1, item2, ...]` shorthand. Both objects are declared as global instance variables.

The first table view creates the second and pushes it onto the navigation controller stack. The headers appear correctly the first time the former view is displayed, and they always display correctly whenever the latter view is displayed, but when I hit back to return to the first view, the section headers match those of the second view. This problem is immediately resolved by changing one of the two variable names, but I would much rather understand why the problem is happening in the first place.

Please let me know if any more information would be helpful. I have no concept of what might be causing this, so I'm not entirely sure what information could be useful.

**Edit:** Here's a simplified version of the way the two objects are set up and interact.
`CalendarViewController.m`:

```
NSMutableArray *sectionHeaders;
@implementation CalendarViewController

-(id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    sectionHeaders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

//this is the method that adds items to the sectionHeaders object with irrelevant information excluded
-(void) distributeEvents {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    if(condition1) {
        if(![sectionHeaders containsObject:@"Today"]) {
            [headers addObject:@"Today"];
        }
    }
    else if(condition2) {
        if(![sectionHeaders containsObject:@"Next week"]) {
            [headers addObject:@"Next week"];
        }
    }
    //et cetera...
}
//the only other time the sectionHeaders object comes up is in
- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return sectionHeaders[section];
}
```

The second object, an `EventViewController`, is initialized when a cell is tapped. It is not created with any variables associated with the `sectionHeaders` object.

`EventViewController.m`:

```
NSArray *sectionHeaders;
@implementation EventViewController

//within the init method
sectionHeaders = @[@"What", @"When", @"Where"];

//later...
- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return sectionHeaders[section];
}
```

That's all the references I make to those objects. I apologize for not having the simplified code in the question to begin with. Hopefully having more context will help.

Comment: Are both UITableViews using the same delegate? My best guess is that your error is in the delegate code.

Comment: "Please let me know if any more information would be helpful" Code? With no code we are left to guessing.

Comment: @MikeZ each table view is its own delegate

Comment: @JoshCaswell I've edited my post to include what is hopefully a sufficient example

Answer (score 0):

From your code it appears that both `sectionHeaders` arrays are defined outside the scope of the corresponding classes and basically are two global variables with same name - in which case linker should have given you a warning.

I suggest you move them inside the class they belong to.